# Find all (a,b) that makes this function continuous

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

$f(x) =
\left[\begin{cases} 
      -\sqrt{3} & x<a \\
      \tan(bx) & a \le x \le 1 \\
      2-x & x > 1 
   \end{cases}\right]$

Find all $(a,b)$ pairs where $a<0$ so that $f(x)$ is continuous on all real numbers.

I can only find $(-\frac{4}{3}, \frac{\pi}{4}$). Is there any other pairs, if so, how do I find it without causing $\tan(bx)$ to not equal $\tan(\frac{\pi}{2})$ or $\tan(-\frac{\pi}{2})$ at the interval $a \le x \le 1$?

Was an exam question and it ended already, just wanted to check my answer and learn more about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We need

- $\tan (b)= 1 \iff b=\frac \pi 4 +k\pi$
- $\tan (ab)= -\sqrt 3 \iff ab=-\frac \pi 3+h\pi $

therefore we need

$$a=\frac{-\frac \pi 3+h\pi}{\frac\pi 4 +k\pi}, \quad b=\frac \pi 4 +k\pi$$

with $k,h \in \mathbb Z$ such that $a<0$ that is

- for $k\ge 0 \implies h\le 0$
- for $k< 0 \implies h> 0$

and $ab\le bx\le b$ with $bx \neq \frac \pi 2 +j\pi$ which leads to

- for $k \ge 0 \implies a=-\frac43$ and $b=\frac \pi 4$
- for $k < 0 \implies$ no solutions

Comment: It's the same as my approach! But, do I need to check for each k and h and verify that in the interval $a \le x \le 1$, the function $\tan(b)$ is continuous? I can only verify for k = 0 and h = 0.

Comment: @Marchotridyo I see your point now. I revise that!

Comment: @Marchotridyo Yes I also find only one solution.

Answer (score 0):

You know you only really need to worry about continuity at $x$ $=$ $a$ and $1$

$\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=-\sqrt{3}=f(a)=\tan(ab)$ hence $\tan(ab)= -\sqrt{3}$. Before getting the general solution of this, we look at:

$\lim\limits_{x\to 1}=1=\tan(b)\implies b = n\pi + \pi/4$. Substituting this in the first equation, $\tan(na\pi+ \pi a/4)=\sqrt{3}$ or, $a=\frac{m\pi - \pi/3}{n\pi+ \pi/4},\quad m,n\in\Bbb Z$

Comment: Let me know if I made a typo while editing.

Comment: you forgot the $=$ after $a$